# Specific period in past

Tags: past-tense, past-perfect, past-simple

If we have to mention day or specific time to tell past which tense should we use, simple past or past perfect?

Suppose I am writing an email on Friday then which sentence should I use?

> On Monday, I had come late to the office and worked for 3 hours.

Or

> On Monday, I came late to the office and worked for 3 hours.

Comment: We use the past perfect when we're referring to an event in the past relative to another event in the past.  For example, *I had worked for three hours before I realized it was Saturday.*  If you're not relating one event to another, just use the simple past.

Answer (score 2):

You should use both verbs in the simple past.  When you express an idea that one past action followed another (two past actions in sequence), you should use both the verbs in the simple past. For examples:

She filled the basket and went to the counter.

He snatched the money and ran away.

So the correct sentence is:

On Monday I came late to the office and worked for 3 hours.